# 'import this' and view it with command 'less'

Tags: python, bash

I'd like to check a word in 'The Zen of Python'.

Firsty, import this from ipython

```
    In [1]: import this
    The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

    Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Explicit is better than implicit.
    Simple is better than complex.
    Complex is better than complicated.
    Flat is better than nested.
    Sparse is better than dense.
    ...
```

Secondly, `Ctrl + F` to search my word on the bash
which display the results from the top of console inconveniently.
I only want to view the result within 'import this'

How can I redirect the content and view it using command `less`?

Comment: If Ctrl+F is only displaying the result from the top of the console, that's really a problem with your console app. I don't know what you're using, but all of the console apps I have on Mac and Linux, including the no-GUI framebuffer console, search through scrollback with Ctrl+F (or Cmd+F on Mac) out of the box.

Comment: Also, the Zen is only 21 lines long, including the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `less`? You can invoke `this` from the command line and pipe the result to `grep`:

```
$ python -m this | grep "[...]"
```

If you want to do the same thing inside IPython, you can use the `%%bash` magic:

```
%%bash
python -m this | grep "[...]"
```

But since you're inside the python interpreter, why not use a string search function, or the `re` module instead?

Comment: ty, use a string search or `re` module is not handy as bash command, in my opinion.